# Shift focus by navigation key using clutter toolkit in c?

Tags: c, gtk, glib, gobject, clutter

I have to create a vertical menu using clutter in C. Can anyone help me how to implement focus shift using the navigation keys for the menu where i want to highlight the focused menu option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to mark the actor that contains all the menu items as reactive, assign to it the key focus using `clutter_actor_grab_key_focus()` and connect to the `key-press-event` signal. then you can use `clutter_event_get_key_symbol()` on the `ClutterEvent` passed to the signal and match it agains key symbols like `CLUTTER_KEY_Down` or `CLUTTER_KEY_Up`.

then there's even the possibility to use `ClutterBindingPool` to handle tuples of (key symbol, modifier) and assign them to a specific callback function.

for more information, see the API reference:

http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterActor.html#clutter-actor-grab-key-focus
  http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterActor.html#ClutterActor-key-press-event
  http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/clutter-Events.html#clutter-event-get-key-symbol
  http://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/clutter-Key-Bindings.html

the list of key symbols in in the clutter-keysyms.h header:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/clutter/tree/clutter/clutter-keysyms.h

there are various recipes in the Cookbook as well:

https://developer.gnome.org/clutter-cookbook/stable/events-handling-key-events.html